# How to properly create/use .aar or .jar file from multple java classes ( single package) to use it in different projects in android studio

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio, aar

i tried many different approaches, to use my library in different projects but in each on of them i failed miserably.

here is what i did for the last try,

I created a module / android library

and inside of them i created my Java Classes (3 to be exact)

this is my moduke's gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

}
```

and than i builded my application.

```
Desktop/SDK/myLib/build/outputs/aar
```

At this location i found out my **myLib-debug.aar**  .aar

i added that to my test project to see if could use my class methods,

compile files('src/main/java/lib/myLib-debug.aar')

i added this to my dependencie and gradle sync didnt return any error,

and when i tried to import the package;

this is what i could import

import com.myLib.android.*;

and it seems fine since my module's package name is com.myLib.android

but when i try to reach my class Methods, nothing shows up.

What am i missing?

Comment: Did you get any final solution ? @iosMessenger Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also facing this exact problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you have another module in the same project and want to depend on it, add a direct module dependency. You can do this via File > Project Structure > Dependencies > + > Module Dependency.

Using this UI will add the following dependency to the module; you don't have to make the modifications to the build script yourself, but this what the UI will do:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':my_module')
}
```